# infowindow is not closing when close button is pressed in google maps v3 markercluster..?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-maps, markerclusterer

**load function**

```
function load() {

                 var cluster = [];
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();         

                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.6145, -24.3418),
                        zoom: 2,
                        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                      });


              // Read the data from example.xml
               downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                  // obtain the attribues of each marker
                  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                  var link = markers[i].getAttribute("link");
                  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

                   var html = "<b>" + '<a href="' + link + '" >' + markers[i].getAttribute("name")  + '</a>' + "</b> <br/>"  + "</b> <br/>" + '<a href="' + link + '" >' + markers[i].getAttribute("address")  + '</a>';

                  var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

                  // create the marker
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                  });


                 addMarker(marker, html);



              cluster.push(marker);

                }
                var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);

                 //markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
              });
   }
```

**add markers**

```
function addMarker(marker, content)
    {


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

       infoWindow.setContent(content);
       infoWindow.open(map, marker);
       infoWindow.close();


     });

    }
```

*code for ajax*

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: "load function function load() {". That's an interesting function you have there.

Comment: Seriously, though, edit your question so the code is properly formatted. It's hard to read as it is.

Comment: I know, but your formatting is terrible so it looks like that's all one line of code.

Comment: Your have an error in your javascript code: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'O'`. This apparently happens somewhere in your heavily obfuscated `main.js`, so good luck with debugging.

Comment: Why call infoWindow.open() and then infoWindow.close() immediately after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the cluster marker, a "clusterclick" event is fired.

Add an event listener an then close the infowindow:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, cluster);

google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
});
```